Will an additional exhaust fan cause backflow in other fans using the same duct trunk?
I need to install an additional hot air exhaust fan and would like your opinion on my options for routing the addition. As this is isn't integral to the home, being used for server and conditioner heat, I'm not worried about code.
The final exhaust is fairly open so there shouldn't be much restriction. Should I be worried about the new 200CFM fan back drafting the others? Should another inline fan be placed near the exit?


Note - if the fans are axial computer-type fans as drawn, they are not going to produce anywhere near the rated airflow in this situation, as they don't cope well with backpressure from ducts. They are rated in the "free air" condition, where there's no intake or exhaust duct adding flow resistance.
I'd suggest a single fan blowing out of the house on the 6" duct, probably a mixed flow axial type as they appear to be the most efficient flavor that will cope well with being ducted, and using duct dampers and/or duct sizing to balance the airflow to the individual end-points (with all of them seeing suction from the one fan, rather than having pressure put into them by the many fans.)
The (existing?) Tee should preferably be a wye for better flow and the "Option A" saddle should again preferably be a Wye directing flow outward rather than a Tee as drawn. A with those modifications or C would appear to be the best arrangement from what's given.

No, the fans are not computer fans... I just thought the icon looked best.

Would a single fan at the end of the 6" out of the house be strong enough to pull from all the different areas? F1/F2 pull from a very small server closet, F3 is from a specific device (so hardly any area), and F4 will also be a specific device that I would want at least 200CFM being sucked from. Is there any harm in keeping the fans that are/will be installed and also adding a lower CFM main exhaust fan? I'll convert the existing tee split on F1/F2 to a wye and also use a wye saddle instead of a straight saddle for F4.

It would depend on the particular fan chosen, of course.  Also on balancing the airflow in the ducts, typically by using dampers. Multiple fans tend to be inefficient, compared to one large enough to do the whole job. There's also a question of where the 425 CFM of air will come from - does the house leak that much easily, or do you also need an outside air intake to prevent depressurizing the house (which gets to be a code and life-safety issue particularly if you have any gas appliances...)

Is 425 CFM enough to really depressurize a 2200sqft house? I've never considered that. I assume it's against the rules, which is why I've been vague, but I do have a gas furnace that is only used when it's below 25°F outside (Colorado Springs, CO), which is F3 actually... F1/F2 is evacuating hot air from my servers that pull fresh air from my office, and F4 is going to be for the newly installed laser cutter (so it won't always need venting, just when turned on). All this is why I've trying to make sure I am getting all the air up and out.

Assuming 8' ceilings, 2200 sq ft is 17,600 CF.  Divide that by 425 and you'll find that the house will be fully depressurized in 42 minutes.  Now, that's unrealistic.  Your 425 CFM fan will be less and less effective as the interior pressure drops.  Also, the 2200 is usually usable area and there are likely unconditioned spaces not included in it.  The  point is that 425 CFM is relatively large next to 2200 sq ft.
